# Git постоянно требует добавить файл в проект

Tags: git

Инициализировал проект, добавил файлы в него, закомитил. Когда изменяю какой либо файл и пытаюсь добавить коммит выдает такое сообщение:

```
$ git commit -m "test"
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
(use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Changes not staged for commit:
    modified:   todo.txt
```

То есть всегда после изменения нужно сперва добавлять файл, а потом комитить или же косяк у меня где то.
Коммичу так: *git commit -m "test"*

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git-%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9

Comment: `git commit -am "test"`

Comment: "То есть всегда после изменения нужно сперва добавлять файл," - это логично. Гит же не знает какие файлы нужно коммитить. Может вам надо в коммит добавить только два из 50-ти изменённых файлов, а не все. Поэтому да - надо в начале добавить, потом коммитить

Comment: @Lexx918 спасибо!

Comment: @СергейМишин теперь разобрался, спасибо! Действительно, можно случайно на менять что то в других файлах, а загрузить нужно только один, поэтому и сперва добавляем потом загружаем

Answer (score 1):

У файла в git есть несколько состояний:

- 'untracked' - файл не добавлен вовсе
- 'unmodified' - файл в репозитории и в нём нет изменений
- 'modified' - файл модифицирован
- 'staged' - файл модифицирован и изменения были проиндексированы

Команда `commit` создаёт новый коммит из *проиндексированных* изменений. Поэтому недостаточно просто изменить файл, его нужно занести проиндексировать.

Чтобы проиндексировать изменения в файле используется команда `add` (или её синоним `stage`). Её можно использовать как с путём к папке
`git add .`, так и с путём к файлу `git add my-file.txt`.

Также можно проиндексировать только часть изменений в файле при помощи `git add -p`. Откроется интерактивное меню, в котором можно выбрать какие изменения нужно добавить.

Также стоит подчеркнуть что @Герман-Борисов добавил ссылку на очень полезный документ, который поможет разобраться с git - книгу ["Pro Git" на русском языке](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git-%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9)